# Is it possible to sync Microsoft Word 2011 for Mac with Google Docs ?

Tags: google-drive, synchronization

Is it possible to sync Microsoft Word 2011 for Mac with Google Docs?

If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't look like it there is a way to do so just between Google Docs and Word 2010 for Mac via the official Google Cloud Connect for Microsoft. There *may* be a 3rd party app that can do the job though. However, that is also unlikely since there isn't any API that is for Mac's version.

#### From Google's Doc Blog ([*Source*](http://googledocs.blogspot.com/2010/11/bridge-to-cloud-google-cloud-connect.html))

> Many of you have also asked about availability for Macs. Unfortunately due to the lack of support for open APIs on Microsoft Office for Mac, we are unable to make Google Cloud Connect available on Macs at this time. We look forward to when that time comes so we can provide this feature to our Mac customers as well.

*Blog was posted: November 22, 2010.*

*Extra information for no cost: There is an iPhone/iPad app related to this: [Documents To Go](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/documents-to-go-office-suite/id317117961?mt=8).*